# Developing iOS 5 with Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, xcode5

Is it possible to build iOS 5.1.1 apps with Xcode 5? Only the 6.0, 6.1, and 7 SDKs are available in the drop down list.

More Information:
I am trying to support my sister's iPhone. She has the 4s but refuses to upgrade any higher. I want to support all versions afterward as well. I don't plan on releasing this to the app store at any time.

Comment: Just set the deployment target to iOS5 and resist from using iOS6 or 7 specific classes/methods.

Comment: Do you want to limit deployment target to ios5 and above or You want to build you app with ios5.1.1 sdk?

Comment: So your sister's iphone's version is iOS5.1.1? It ok that you can use ios 7 sdk and set deployment target to ios5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the most recent SDK. You should always use the newest SDK.

Set your *deployment target* to the lowest iOS version you want to support.

When using an API or class only available on iOS 6 or 7, you'll need to check if it exists first.

The recently released iOS Tech Talks videos on developer.apple.com contain an excellent presentation that shows clever ways to do this simply.

DO NOT follow any instructions that tell you to copy old SDKs into the Xcode app bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Since you updated your question, so should I.

You don't need to build your app with ios5.1.1 depending on your condition, just set development target to ios5 and "building with ios7 sdk" is ok.

If you really want to build your app with ios 5.1.1, here is the answer.

First You should download ios5.1.1 sdk first which XCode 5 don't have by default.

Then copy the ios5.1.1 sdk to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs and restart your XCode.

You will find it in Base SDK(Build settings - Architectures)

Comment: No, don't do this. This is not supported by Apple, and starting in February, everything will need to be built against the iOS 7 SDK.

Comment: @AaronBrager I know it but I think it is just a question.

Comment: What do you mean you think it is just a question?

Comment: @AaronBrager Maybe mrplants just want to know how to build app with ios5.1.1 sdk and he don't plan to use it to submit to appstore.